# Edges com valores incorretos

Tags: r, grafo

Ao rodar o código abaixo, não obtenho a representação gráfica esperada. Apesar de A estar ligado a C com valor 90.16 no plot a ligação A – C apresenta o valor 80. Alguém consegue ajudar?

```
library(igraph)

df1 <- data.frame(origem=c( "A", "B", "B"),
                  destino=c("C", "A", "B"),
                  valor=c(90.16,80,100))

grafo11 <- graph_from_data_frame(df1, directed = FALSE)

plot(simplify(grafo11, remove.loops = TRUE, remove.multiple = TRUE),
     vertex.color = c("gold","skyblue")[1+(V(grafo11)$name=="B")],
     edge.label = E(grafo11)$valor)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sempre inclua no seu código as bibliotecas utilizadas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está plotando o grafo simplificado, mas fornecendo para o rótulo os valores do grafo completo. Coloque o grafo simplificado em um novo objeto, indicando para o `simplify` o que fazer com atributos caso precisem ser agregados (o padrão é descartar qualquer um que não seja *weight* ou *name* - veja a ajuda para `attribute.combination` para detalhes).

```
grafo.s <- simplify(grafo11, edge.attr.comb = "sum")

plot(grafo.s, edge.label = E(grafo.s)$valor)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Troquei o argumento `directed` em `graph_from_data_frame` para `TRUE` e funcionou corretamente em meu computador.

```
grafo11 <- graph_from_data_frame(df1, directed = TRUE)
```

Comment: No meu caso, o grafo não é direcionado por esse motivo usei directed = FALSE